# How can I test a Spring controller that uses JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring controller that looks like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public List<Foo> byName(@PathVariable String name) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        List<Foo> result = template.query("SELECT * FROM FOOS WHERE FOO_NM = :name", params, new FooRowMapper());
        if (result.size() == 0) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, String.format("foo %s not found", name));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to test this. I can do a basic "Spring can set it up" test:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class FooControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private FooController controller;

    @Test
    public void canCreate() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(controller);
    }
}
```

But I'm not certain what the right way to test, for example, the `byName` method is. Do I need to mock something? Can I just test it like a plain Java method (call it with whatever parameters and assert the output)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research and help from the posted answers, I moved the retrieval code into a service:

```java
@Service
public class FooService implements IFooService {
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    // the only method of IFooService
    @Override
    public List<FormulaFunction> getAllByName(String name) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        return template.query("SELECT * FROM FOOS WHERE FOO_NM = :name", params, new FooRowMapper());
    }
}
```

In testing the controller, that service is mocked using Mockito:

```java
@WebMvcTest(FooController.class)
public class FooControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private IFooService service;

    @Autowired
    private FooController controller;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void canCreate() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(controller);
    }

    /**
     * Test that controller properly returns 404 when no results are found
     */
    @Test
    public void test404() throws Exception {
        doReturn(new ArrayList<>()).when(service).getAllByName("bars");
        this.mvc.perform(get("/foo/bars")).andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best at all for testing my controllers (I also started not too long ago)
And well, I mockup my controller.

```
class UserControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
void addUserTest() throws Exception {
    String content = "{" +
            "\"username\": \"test\"," +
            "\"password\": \"tesT1234\"," +
            "\"email\": \"test@test.com\"" +
            "}";

    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/users/signup")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(content))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

For example here for a signup user, I build a JSON content and send it to my mock. I check the final status to see if it creates the user.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to mock something?

It depends on what exactly you need to test.
If you write a unit test - then you usually mock external dependencies as you assume, that they will follow some contract.

> Can I just test it like a plain Java method (call it with whatever parameters and assert the output)?

Of course, you can, but it will mean that you're testing a bean method, but not the full flow from receiving a http request and returning the response.

If you need to do an end-to-end test you need to run your app and then call your HTTP methods and verify response. For that you can use [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) as described in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to make a controller that uses JDBC itself.
It's much better to use `Controller-Service-Repository pattern`.

So your code in the Foo controller can be like:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {
  @Autowired
  private FooService fooService;
  
  @GetMapping("/{name}")
  public ResponseEntity<?> byName(@PathVariable String name) {
    final List<Foo> list = fooService.getFooByName(name);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
  }
}
```

For testing purposes it's better to use MockMvc:

```java
// In the Foo controller
@GetMapping("/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> byName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello, " + name);
}

// In the Test class
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private FooController fooController;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(fooController, is(notNullValue()));
    }

    @Test
    public void getUser() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foo/Joe"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn().getResponse();

        assertThat(response.getContentAsString(), is("Hello, Joe"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test it like a regular Java method or use MockMvc to perform a get request to the relewant path.

It would be nice if you posted the body of your method (right now it’s hard to help).

Comment: I've added the method body, hope it helps.

Comment: As I said: learn a bit about MockMvc (it's quite straightforward) or just test it like a normal method.